# I want to find Biggest Change

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, math, foreach

my script is not working only printing the last token in data,
my script should print zil because it Biggest Change in my data

```
var olddata = 
[
    {"token": "NORD", "oldprice": 1},
    {"token": "DYP", "oldprice": 2.43},
    {"token": "ZIL", "oldprice": 0.20},
    {"token": "VET", "oldprice": 6.33}
]

var newdata = 
[
    {"token": "NORD", "newprice": 1.20},
    {"token": "DYP", "newprice": 2.80},
    {"token": "ZIL", "newprice": 0.40},
    {"token": "VET", "newprice": 6.90}
]
function findBiggestChange(oldData, newData) {
  var previousDifference = null;
  var changeIndex;
  oldData.forEach((obj, i) => {
    var data = newData.find(d => d.token === obj.token);
        var currentDifference = previousDifference ? Math.abs.forEach(data.newprice - obj.oldprice) : data.newprice;
        changeIndex = currentDifference > previousDifference ? i : 0;
  });
}

findBiggestChange(olddata,newdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "biggest change" by quantity, your program is correct. Because:

> ZIL: 0.40 - 0.20 = 0.20

> VET: 6.90 - 6.33 = 0.57 (VET increase is quantitatively higher)

If your "biggest change" is by percentage, then you need to change the way you check changes in percentage rather than quantitative terms. In this case, the biggest change is...:

> ZIL: 0.40/0.20 = 2 => 2 - 1 = 1 = 100% (ZIL percentage increase is higher)

> VET: 6.90/6.33 = 1.09 => 1.09 - 1 = 0.09 = 9%
> VET: 6.90/6.33 = 1.09 => 1.09 - 1 = 0.09 = 9%

In case your "biggest change" is by **percentage**, the code you're looking for is:

```js
var olddata = 
[
    {"token": "NORD", "oldprice": 1},
    {"token": "DYP", "oldprice": 2.43},
    {"token": "ZIL", "oldprice": 0.20},
    {"token": "VET", "oldprice": 6.33}
];

var newdata = 
[
    {"token": "NORD", "newprice": 1.20},
    {"token": "DYP", "newprice": 2.80},
    {"token": "ZIL", "newprice": 0.40},
    {"token": "VET", "newprice": 6.90}
];

function findBiggestChange(oldData, newData) {
  var biggestDifference = -Infinity;
  var biggestChangeObject = null;
  oldData.forEach(obj => {
    var data = newData.find(d => d.token === obj.token);
    var currentDifference = (data.newprice/obj.oldprice) - 1;
    
    if (currentDifference > biggestDifference) {
        biggestDifference = currentDifference;
        biggestChangeObject = obj;
    }
  });
  return biggestChangeObject;
}

console.log(findBiggestChange(olddata,newdata));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives you the zil object as result because it has the highest difference.

```js
var olddata = 
[
    {"token": "NORD", "oldprice": 1},
    {"token": "DYP", "oldprice": 2.43},
    {"token": "ZIL", "oldprice": 0.20},
    {"token": "VET", "oldprice": 6.33}
]

var newdata = 
[
    {"token": "NORD", "newprice": 1.20},
    {"token": "DYP", "newprice": 2.80},
    {"token": "ZIL", "newprice": 0.40},
    {"token": "VET", "newprice": 6.90}
]
function findBiggestChange(oldData, newData) {
  var previousDifference = null;
  var changeIndex;
  oldData.forEach((obj, i) => {
    var data = newData.find(d => d.token === obj.token);
    var currentDifference = (data.newprice/obj.oldprice) - (1);
    if (!previousDifference) {
        previousDifference = currentDifference;
    }  
    if (currentDifference > previousDifference) {
        changeIndex = i;
        previousDifference = currentDifference;
    }
  });
  return oldData[changeIndex];
}

console.log(findBiggestChange(olddata,newdata));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a list of changes, both absolute (change) and percentage (percentageChange).

Using [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), we'll then sort in descending order of percentage change to get the largest change in percentage terms:

```js
const olddata = [ {"token": "NORD", "oldprice": 1}, {"token": "DYP", "oldprice": 2.43}, {"token": "ZIL", "oldprice": 0.20}, {"token": "VET", "oldprice": 6.33} ]
const newdata = [ {"token": "NORD", "newprice": 1.20}, {"token": "DYP", "newprice": 2.80}, {"token": "ZIL", "newprice": 0.40}, {"token": "VET", "newprice": 6.90} ] 

// Get the percentage change and absolute change of each value...
const changes = olddata.map(({token, oldprice}, idx) => {
    const change = (newdata[idx].newprice - oldprice);
    const percentageChange = 100 * change / oldprice;
    return { token, percentageChange, change };
});

// Sort by percentage change, in descending order
const sortedByPercentChange = changes.sort((a, b) => b.percentageChange - a.percentageChange);

console.log("All changes (sorted on % change):", sortedByPercentChange)

// The largest change will be the first element...
console.log("Largest % change:", sortedByPercentChange[0])
```